# MySQL : How to write a query for the below scenario that image represents?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I tried, But my query loading too much data for calculating this one.
please suggest me, how to write single query for this scenario.

Comment: please tag the appropriate database. it can't be oracle and mysql

Comment: What query did you try?

Comment: You definitely need JOINs here but in order for people to help you here, you need to post what query you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged the question with mysql here how you can do it

```
select
t1.id,
t1.user_name,
sum(case when t2.shop_status = 'returned' then 1 else 0 end)  as `num_of_return`,
sum(case when t2.shop_status = 'shopped' then 1 else 0 end)  as `num_of_shopped`,
sum(case when t2.shop_status = 'cancelled' then 1 else 0 end)  as `num_of_cancelled`
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.id
group by t1.id
```